# ListBox.ItemTemplate with a custom control template inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone application. I have defined a ListBox.ItemTemplate's DataTemplate as follows:

```
<ListBox Margin="10,10,8,8" x:Name="ChoicesList">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="ListBoxItemLayout" Background="Transparent" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="0.281*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="0.719*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="100"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
          <TextBlock x:Name="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}"/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="Rating" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Rating}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to convert all the content inside the ListBoxItem as a Control because I want to add a Click event to it.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `MouseLeftButtonUp` on your ListBoxItemLayout Grid?

Comment: Yes: I'm very new on silverlight development.

Comment: A solution (not the only one) can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bffb1cfc-cd2d-4af6-a306-32972ed3874d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blend you can just use the "Make into Control" option.

You should also consider using the "SelectionChanged" event on the listbox, rather than a click (tap) on the control.