# C# Xaml ListBox Template Add in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox

I did some research about the listbox but i didnt understand how to solve my problem.
I have a Listbox in my xaml page and i want to add now a listviewitem using the Template (so i get toggle button and so on) not in xaml and with the help of c#. How do i do this? Thx for your help

```
 <ListBox x:Name="Listbox" Background="Red">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateGrid">
                    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="Toggle" Foreground="Black">
                        <ToggleSwitch.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </ToggleSwitch.Background>
                    </ToggleSwitch>
                    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="26" x:Name="Text" Foreground="Black">Test</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What type of object are you intending to add to the Listbox?  A manually created ListViewItem object or some custom object?

Comment: I want to add a Listviewitem using this template and during adding i want to custumize the content of the textblock , and i dont find  a way to do this sadly :(

Comment: Something like this guy did:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408046/listbox-itemtemplate-with-a-custom-control-template-inside-datatemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listbox will use the template automatically.  From your code, just call `Listbox.Items.Add(obj)`. One thing to note though - in your data template I don't see that you are specifying a datatype for your data template to target, so it will use a generic display by calling `ToString()` on your object.

Comment: If i create a new Listviewitem and add it over Listbox.Items.Add(listviewitemxy); it doesnt display ... And it doesnt allow me to specify my datatype...

Comment: i did the following coding: listviewitem x = new listviewitem; Then i set the content template to my data template, and wrote Listbox.Items.Add(x); but it doesnt display anything

Comment: Can you use a ListBoxItem instead?

Comment: If i manuelley add the Listboxitem in xaml i dont see it, and if i add a listviewitem manually in xaml it looks like the thing i want to achieve in c# :( Whats the difference between listview and listboxitem?